# ActionScript 3 sprite, width and height 0 unsure why

Tags: actionscript-3, width, sprite

Im currently trying to bring in an image where the mouse clicks but to get the tip of the pin to line up where I need it to i need to offset its x and y by a certain amount which needs to use the width and height for later stages of this but it always returns 0 for both properties, I have copied code that had worked fine on previous projects in and  still nothing.
Any help appreciated.

split up the code to make it easier

declaration

```
public var pin1:Sprite, pin2:Sprite, pin3:Sprite;
```

function to dynamically add pins

```
public function SetPoint(e:ContextMenuEvent):void
        {
            //trace("click option");
            //place a square
            this["pin" + (pinNum)] = addPin("Images/pin.png","pin" + pinNum,mouseX,mouseY,Sprite);

            var tempX = this["pin"+(pinNum - 1)].height;

            trace(tempX);
            this["pin"+(pinNum - 1)].x = mouseX - (this["pin"+(pinNum - 1)].width/2);
            this["pin"+(pinNum - 1)].y = mouseY - (this["pin"+(pinNum - 1)].height);


            trace(mouseX);
            trace(mouseX - (this["pin"+(pinNum - 1)].width/2));
            //pin.x = 0-(pin.width/2);
            //pin.y = 0;

        }
```

my actual function to dynamically import images

```
//function to create sprites
    public function addPin(imgURL:String, imgName:String, imgX:uint, imgY:uint, objType:Class):*
    {
        var imageURL: URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        var image:* = new (objType);
        imageURL.url = imgURL;
        imageLoader.load(imageURL);
        image.addChild(imageLoader);
        stage.addChild(image);
        image.x = imgX;
        image.y = imgY;
        image.name = imgName;
        image.scaleX = 0.1;
        image.scaleY = 0.1;
        pinNum = pinNum + 1;
        return image;
    }
```

I dont mind where I am able to read the width and height of the image being imported as I will just set it to a global variable but any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I can't truly understand what's the `width` to, as you are pointing to some pin arrays, but as there are Loaders, the image should be loaded first, and then you can use the width. It's 0 before the image is loaded.

Comment: I know its called after the image appears on the stage so the image has to be loaded into the sprite. the pin is just the name of the image its set up dynamically to keep adding pins and to reference them dynamically, no arrays. so in the set point function it doesnt return a width or height